# Printing object argument?

Tags: java, object, casting

I have a class named `MyInteger`; I created a `MyInteger` object and passed a value through it. Is there a way I can print the number that is being passed through in my main method?

```
MyInteger int5 = new MyInteger(56);
System.out.println(MyInteger.isEven(int5));
```

Prints out "true" since 56 is an even number but I want the number "56" to be printed in my print-statement without actually typing "56".

I don't even know if this can be done? I've tried Casting/StringOf/ValueOf?

Comment: You should show the code of `MyInteger` class. (and `isEven` should probably not be a static method)

Comment: Either you add a getter in your `MyInteger` class or you just store your 56 to a variable before passing it to the constructor so that you can print it out on the next line.

Comment: Your int5 object would be storing the int value internally in a variable. If this variable is public, `System.out.print(int5.variable)` should do it, else add a getValue function to MyInteger class , so you can call it as `System.out.println(int.getValue())`

Answer (score 0):

That value ***56*** passed in the constructor is for sure assigned to a field in the **MyInteger** class...

You need then to use the getter in order to retrieve it back...

Something like `MyInteger#getValue ();`

```
 System.out.println(int5.getValue ());
```